# How to avoid UnsupportedOperationException while getting percent symbols?

Tags: java, android, decimalformat

I was trying to get the percent symbol specific to the locale. My crash logs show "UnsupportedOperationException" while trying to getPercent from DecimalFormatSymbols.

I used NumberFormat instance for the given locale and got the percent symbol through DecimalFormatSymbols getPercent method.

```
    {
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = (DecimalFormat)NumberFormat.getInstance(currentLocale);
        return String.valueOf(decimalFormat.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getPercent());
    }
```

I was expecting the percent symbol specific to the locale, but for some locales, I am getting the following exception

```
       at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.getPercent(DecimalFormatSymbols.java:352
```

I checked DecimalFormatSymbols class getPercent() method,

```
public char getPercent() {
        if (percent.length() == 1) {
            return percent.charAt(0);
        }
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Percent spans multiple characters: " + percent);
    }
```

Looks like percent symbol length != 1, it's happening for Arabic symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when looking at class [DecimalFormatSymbols](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html), method `.getPercent()` simply returns a `%` sign...

for Arabic, you might need to call `.setPercent("٪")` first, so that `.getPercent()` would return `٪`.

In Java, it's `Character.charCount()` equals `1`.

Comment: Thanks. I need to show the percent symbol on UI based on the locale, I don't want to hard code it. Why for Arabic alone it throws an exception. Also, it's not happening every time. Probably if i don't receive the better suggestion, have to go with hardcoding the percent symbol.

Comment: @Madhan just add a format-string to string resources and use that to format `٪` or `%` (depending on the `Locale`). they are also being displayed on different sides of the percentage value.

Comment: Thanks @Martin, will do that.